# Java collections: Compare elements in collection with each other and remove in one cycle

Tags: java, collections

Say, I have a collection of some geolocations (in format `Country > Region [ > Town [ > District]]`) and I want to remove  locations that overlap each other (for example, `Europe > Germany` overlaps `Europe > Germany > Dresden` and `Europe > Germany > Hamburg`, so the last two must be removed). I see that I need two instances of iterators to make something like this:

```
final Iterator<Location> outerIterator = locations.newIterator();
while (outerIterator.hasNext()) {
    final Location outer = outerIterator.next();
    final Iterator<Location> innerIterator = locations.newIterator();
    while (innerIterator.hasNext()) {            
        final Location inner = innerIterator.next();
        if (!inner.equals(outer)) {
            if (inner.overlaps(outer)) outerIterator.remove();
            else if (outer.overlaps(inner)) innerIterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't get new `Iterator` for the same collection. Is my algorithm incorrect or there is a way to do it right?

---

The final code using the advice from the [answer provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235627/java-collections-compare-elements-in-collection-with-each-other-and-remove-in-on/3235666#3235666) by [Carl Smotricz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25829/carl-smotricz) looks like this:

```
final Iterator<JobLocation> outerIterator = locations.iterator();
while (outerIterator.hasNext()) {
    final JobLocation outer = outerIterator.next();         
    final Iterator<JobLocation> innerIterator = locations.iterator();
    while (innerIterator.hasNext()) {
        final JobLocation inner = innerIterator.next();
        if (!inner.equals(outer) && inner.overlaps(outer)) {
            outerIterator.remove();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should consider a better data structure for this, something hierarchical like a tree perhaps. It'll make your life much easier. Things will be more manageable, readable, faster, etc.

Comment: The problem that this code is for GWT and it is already a little bit complicated. The hierarchical tree in fact is kept on the server-side, I get just already computed instances for client through RPC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove an object from the outer iterator, you need to break out of the inner loop immediately afterwards. I'm not sure if that will solve your problem completely, but it may get you a bit further along.

If there's still a problem, please show the error message and/or exception!

Comment: I need to remove several elements, so I can't break here.

In case of the code in example I get in frequent cases `ConcurrentModificationException`, which follow logic of collections, but not an answer for my question

Comment: If you just removed the object the outer loop was pointing to, there is absolutely no sense in continuing the inner loop, which compares elements with the recently deceased `outer`. I'm advocating breaking out of the inner loop, not both. Think about it!

Comment: Yes, you are exactly right, I'll add the final code in the question

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you meant to increment your outerIterator in the inner loop?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should opt to use a different structure for your regions, like a tree where each location has children that are contained by it. This way you can exclude all regions that overlap another after a simple look-up. No nested iterations needed.

This is easier if no location can overlap with two locations, which seems to be the case.